# Make chinese texts be divided in blocks

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn html and css, and i'm trying to figure it out how to make languages that allow for vertical writing (chinese, mongolian, japanese, etc) to have their paragraphs begin in the right part of the screen, start new lines left of the previous ones and then start a new row after the previous one end. it would end up something like this:

| paragraph 4 | paragraph 3 | paragraph 2 | paragraph 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| paragraph 8 | paragraph 7 | paragraph 6 | paragraph 5 |
| paragraph 12 | paragraph 11 | paragraph 10 | paragraph 9 |

Is this possible? Thank you.

I tried set the width and height properties in the css, but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

edit:
I know how to make the text go vertical, top to botton, right to left. I want to know if it is possible to make the text break and start again below once it reaches the screen width.

```css
p {
  dir: rtl;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-indent: 0em;
  text-align: justify;
  height: 50vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

.chinese {
  font-family: 'Noto Serif TC', serif;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  width: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <item id="mainpage">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet_CN.css">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif+TC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Example text in Chinese characters (vertical)</h1>

  <section class="chinese">

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam ultricies dapibus nulla cursus accumsan. Proin tempor neque id libero dignissim condimentum. Vivamus malesuada, dolor nec dapibus sagittis, metus magna ultricies sem, ac lobortis justo eros ac enim. Nulla bibendum tellus tellus, quis ultricies mi efficitur sed. Suspendisse malesuada sapien eu felis vehicula, quis bibendum sapien maximus. Sed sollicitudin lobortis rhoncus. Nulla sit amet nulla ante.</p>


</section>

</body>

</html>
```

I couldn't use chinese text here.

Comment: Sorry, I find the description a bit confusing. As you asking how to display Chinese in vertical and right to left?

Comment: from its inception HTML (SGML) was designed to incorporate international writing conventions. I let you discover the existence of documentation written since 1993 on this subject; like here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode